# Highlight parent menu when submenu is clicked in Jquery for accordion menu

Tags: jquery, menu, accordion

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  // initialize accordion
  $('.acd ul').each(function() {
    var currentURI = window.location.href;
    var links = $('a', this);
    var collapse = true;
    for (var i = 0; i < links.size(); i++) {
      var elem = links.eq(i);
      var href = elem.attr('href');
      var hrefLength = href.length;
      var compareTo = currentURI.substr(-1 * hrefLength);
      if (href == compareTo) {
        collapse = false;
        break;
      }
    };
    if (collapse) {
      $(this).hide();
    }
  });

  // on click, show this element and hide all others
  $('.acd > li').click(function() {
    var me = $(this).children('ul');
    $('.acd ul').not(me).slideUp('normal');
    me.slideDown('normal');
  });
});
```

```css
.acd,
.acd ul,
.acd li,
.acd a,
.acd span {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  border-radius: 2px;
  -moz-border-radius: 2px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 2px;
}

.acd li {
  list-style: none;
}

.acd li>a {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  min-width: 110px;
  padding: 0 10px 0 40px;
  color: #fdfdfd;
  font: bold 12px/32px Arial, sans-serif;
  text-decoration: none;
  text-shadow: 0px 1px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, .35);
  background: #616975;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, rgb(114, 122, 134) 0%, rgb(80, 88, 100) 100%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, rgb(114, 122, 134)), color-stop(100%, rgb(80, 88, 100)));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, rgb(114, 122, 134) 0%, rgb(80, 88, 100) 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, rgb(114, 122, 134) 0%, rgb(80, 88, 100) 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, rgb(114, 122, 134) 0%, rgb(80, 88, 100) 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(top, rgb(114, 122, 134) 0%, rgb(80, 88, 100) 100%);
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, .1), 0px 1px 0px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, .1), 0px 1px 0px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
  box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, .1), 0px 1px 0px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
}

.acd li>a span {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 7px;
  right: 0;
  padding: 0 10px;
  margin-right: 10px;
  font: normal bold 12px/18px Arial, sans-serif;
  background: #404247;
  -webkit-border-radius: 15px;
  -moz-border-radius: 15px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2), 1px 1px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, .1);
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2), 1px 1px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, .1);
  box-shadow: inset 1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .2), 1px 1px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, .1);
}

.smenu li a {
  color: #878d95;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, .2);
  background: #f2f2f2;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #d6d6d6;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, .1), 0px 1px 0px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, .1), 0px 1px 0px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
  box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 0px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, .1), 0px 1px 0px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, .1);
}

.smenu li:last-child a {
  border: none;
}

.smenu li>a span {
  color: #797979;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, .2);
  background: transparent;
  border: 1px solid #c9c9c9;
  -webkit-box-shadow: none;
  -moz-box-shadow: none;
  box-shadow: none;
}

.smenu em {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  margin-left: 14px;
  color: #a6a6a6;
  font: normal 10px/32px Arial, sans-serif;
}

.acd>li:target>a,
.acd>li>a.active {
  color: #00121c;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(255, 255, 255, .2);
  /*background: url(../img/active.png) repeat-x;*/
  background: #0088cd;
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #0088cd 0%, #00669a 100%);
  background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%, #0088cd), color-stop(100%, #00669a));
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #0088cd 0%, #00669a 100%);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(top, #0088cd 0%, #00669a 100%);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #0088cd 0%, #00669a 100%);
  background: linear-gradient(top, #0088cd 0%, #00669a 100%);
}

.smenu li:hover a {
  background: #f7f7f7;
}

.acd li>.smenu {
  display: block;
}

.acd li:target>.smenu {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="acd">
  <li class="item1">
    <a href="#">Parent 1</a>
    <ul class="smenu">
      <li><a href="subpage1">Child 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="subpage2">Child 2</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
  <li class="item2">
    <a href="#">Parent 2</a>
    <ul class="smenu">
      <li><a href="subpage3">Child 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="subpage4">Child 2</a></li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

With reference to [**this question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25498118/how-to-highlight-parent-menu-when-submenu-is-clicked-in-jquery-for-accordion-men/25498420#25498420).

I wanted the accordion menu to drop down and highlight the parent when the child menu is clicked, the dropdown menu is supposed to remain open for the clicked link with parent `li` highlighted.

Currently dropdown of submenu remains open according to the current url. All I need to add now is to highlight the parent of the dropdown submenu. Can someone kindly assist me on this.

Thanks!

Comment: remove `e.preventDefault();`

Comment: i removed it and now the dropdown works, however the parent highlight appears split sec after child link is clicked and is back to non-highlighted.

Comment: on clicking the child, where do you want to navigate to?

Comment: i have subpages which have this menu on the left layout.

Comment: Also, some parent might not have child and by itself is a link, upon clicked is highlighted as well.

Comment: since its unable to work, how about i just want to highlight the parent (regardless whether it has child or not), whenever parent link or child link is clicked? can u help me please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> -> currently it is able to do so except that the link for the child seem
>   to be disabled

Because of  : e.preventDefault();
Which has prevented the page to redirect to the url in anchor tag.

---

> -> i have subpages which have this menu on the left layout.

When you are navigating to different pages with menu on each of them then either you will have to set the `active` class on each page yourself, so that when the page is loaded, menu is already active to indicate on which page you are.

Or if you want to do it automatically then try this : http://jsfiddle.net/rd35goyt/1/ (cant be tested there)

```
$('.smenu > li > a').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    highlight($(this));
    window.location.href = $(this).prop('href') + "#" + $(this).prop("id");
});
function highlight($elem) {
    // reset previously sliding ul
    $('.acd > li > a.active').next('ul').slideUp();
    $('.acd > li > a').removeClass('active');

    $elem.closest('ul').prev('a').addClass('active');
    $elem.closest('ul').slideDown();
}
var type = window.location.hash.substr(1);
highlight($("#"+type));
```

**html**

```
<ul class="acd">
    <li class="item1"> <a href="#">Parent 1</a>

        <ul class="smenu">
            <li><a href="subpage1" id="c1">Child 1</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="subpage2" id="c2">Child 2</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="item2"> <a href="#">Parent 2</a>

        <ul class="smenu">
            <li><a href="subpage3" id="c3">Child 1</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="subpage4" id="c4">Child 2</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Notice : `id` for child links.

It basically :

1. Sends id of the child link clicked to the next sub-page.
2. On the sub-page it extracts the id and calls `highlight()` function to highlight required parent.

**UPDATE**

```
$('.smenu > li > a').on('click', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    highlight($(this));
    window.location.href = $(this).prop('href') + "#" + $(this).parent().prop("id");
});
function highlight($elem) {
    // reset previously sliding ul
    $('.acd > li > a.active').next('ul').slideUp();
    $('.acd > li > a').removeClass('active');

    $elem.closest('ul').prev('a').addClass('active');
    $elem.closest('ul').slideDown();
}
var type = window.location.hash.substr(1);
highlight($("#" + type + " a"));
```

**html**

```
<ul class="acd">
    <li class="item1"> <a href="#">Parent 1</a>

        <ul class="smenu">
            <li id="c1"><a href="subpage1">Child 1</a>
            </li>
            <li id="c2"><a href="subpage2">Child 2</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="item2"> <a href="#">Parent 2</a>

        <ul class="smenu">
            <li id="c3"><a href="subpage3">Child 1</a>
            </li>
            <li id="c4"><a href="subpage4">Child 2</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Notice : `id` for li.

**UPDATE**

For the `li`s without `ul` as child.

http://jsfiddle.net/rd35goyt/2/

```
$('.acd > li').click(function () {
    var me = $(this).children('ul');
    if(me.length===0){
        $(this).children().addClass("active");
        return;
    }
    $('.acd ul').not(me).slideUp('normal');
    me.slideDown('normal');

});
```

Comment: Hi, it does not work, when i click on child link, the dropdown immediately close and highlighting of parent does not work too.

Comment: The menu resides in a left layout template file in yii and every page is supposed to load this menu on the left.

Comment: was hoping to get the accordtion menu similar to the one here: http://www.menucool.com/vertical/accordion-menu

Comment: seems to work but the page seem to scroll all the way to bottom after loading?

Comment: i am still unable to set id to the href as i am using yii. <li><?php echo CHtml::link('Child1',array('/moduleID/default/link1')); ?></li>, any other ways without having to set id to child links?

Comment: every parent is expanded now, is it possible to make the unclicked parents collapse and the clicked parent expanded? is it due to my css? .acd li > .smenu {
    display: block;
}
 
.acd li:target > .smenu {
    display: block;
}

Comment: can i ask u another question? Let say Parent 3 is without any submenu, can i make it highlighted when i click on it?

Comment: Check the latest update for the required change. Enjoy!

Comment: I tried it but when i put a link to Parent3 and click on Parent3 link, Parent3 page loads but Parent3 on menu isnt highlighted :(

Comment: sorry but now the highlight for those with submenu goes missing when submenu links are clicked, and the parent3 also did not highlight when page loaded.

Comment: i pasted the codes on ur latest fiddle, the highlights work but links no longer works..

Answer (score 0):

thats happening you have prevented the anchor tag from doing its default behviour here

`$('.smenu > li > a').on('click',function(e){
           e.preventDefault();`

so the only of making the anchor tag to redirect to respective href would be by  manually redirecting the page based on the href value.

`window.location.href=$(this).attr('href');`

**JS FIDDLE for Live demo:**

http://jsfiddle.net/dreamweiver/Lnuvu5ru/1/

Happy Coding :)

Comment: Hi, i updated with your codes but still the same, i suspect maybe my css has a problem? I have updated the css to my question can u help to look into it please?

Comment: well there is few glitches with traditional way of doing this, so i have tried to use the jquery`s inbuilt animate method, which gives you smooth scrolling and most importantly you can control it however you want it. here you go http://jsfiddle.net/dreamweiver/Lnuvu5ru/9/

Comment: @esiaz: did you try the jsfiddle ?  the href value of the child element being clicked and the target subpage`s ID needs to be same

Comment: I`m not sure what you tried but the example on jsfiddle is working as intended

Comment: was hoping to get the accordtion menu similar to the one here: http://www.menucool.com/vertical/accordion-menu

Comment: dropdown for current child's parent works but parent highlights for split second and gone. can u try testing with my css? thanks

Answer (score 0):

dunno if i got your question the right way... so: first of all, you wanted to click a main item to display the sub menu and if you click the sub item, you want to highlight the main item?

if so, this is my [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gspnrzqr/5/):

i changed your html markup a little bit - the class names for the main items is always the same. if you need to address a single main item somehow, use the id. i also added classes for mainItem li's and subItem li's, so you may address them directly in your css :

```
<ul class="menu">
    <li class="mainItem" id="itemOne"> <a href="#">Parent 1</a>

        <ul class="subMenu">
            <li class="subItem"><a href="#">Child 1</a>

            </li>
            <li class="subItem"><a href="#">Child 2</a>

            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

the script is rather simple - i created two "handler" classes for the main menu items the selected and the opened class:
first of all, hide all subMenus

```
$(".subMenu").hide();
```

create the click function

```
$(".mainItem").click(function () {
```

first of all, check if the clicked mainItem is not already opened:

```
    if (!$(this).hasClass("openedGroup")) {
    //don't forget the ! at the beginning of the if statement. we want to check on the 
    //false condition
```

if the clicked mainItem is 'unopened', we first slide in the opened mainItem, and reset our "open" handler

```
        $(".openedGroup > .subMenu").stop(true, true).slideUp(400);
        $(".mainItem").removeClass("openedGroup");
```

then we set the "open" handler to our clicked class, and slide it in

```
        $(this).addClass("openedGroup");
        $('.subMenu', this).stop(true, true).slideDown(400);
    }
});
```

you said, that some main items have no submenu. therefore i added the class 'noSubMenu' to the the mainItem li and inserted this over here:

```
if ($(this).hasClass("noSubMenu")) {
    $(".mainItem").removeClass("selectedGroup");
    $(this).addClass("selectedGroup");
}
```

the subItem Click function is quite short. first of all, we remove the selected handler from all main items, then we set it to the parent main item of the clicked subitem.
since the direct parent of the subitem li is the submenu ul, we use parents() and the class selector for the mainitem. the selectedGroup class gets a different background via css...

```
$(".subItem").click(function (e) {
    e.stopPropagation();
    $(".mainItem").removeClass("selectedGroup");
    $(this).parents(".mainItem").addClass("selectedGroup");    
});
```

Comment: just read your comment, that there are mainItems without subMenu, that need to get highlighted too... here's the update: http://jsfiddle.net/gspnrzqr/3/

Comment: Hi, i tried your solution but it closes all submenu when a child is clicked

Comment: tweaked the fiddle, to close an opened sub by clicking on the main: http://jsfiddle.net/gspnrzqr/5/
add e.stopPropagation to your child click function, to prevent it from calling the parent click function!

Comment: still doesnt work. menu all closed and highlight lost when submenu link is clicked.

Comment: since you already marked another answer as correct, i assume u don't need any more support?

Comment: sorry but theres some minor problem now on highlighting of parent which do not have submenu when the url for barren parent is clicked n loaded.

Comment: have you an updated version of your own fiddle, so we can have a look at it?
and have you read and understood my fiddle? it's working there...

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/wesgara9/ here it is. Parent 3 does not highlight when clicked and its page loaded. Thanks

Comment: i'm sry - your example completely differs from mine - i fear i'm not able to find your mistake...
this may be, 'cause i don't like selectors like .class > element > element. i prefer direct selectors via classnames and/or identifier...

Comment: can post your solution for me to try?